# Asymmetric graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am working from the book, "Invitation to Discrete Math." On page 117 there's a question that asks to construct an Asymmetric graph. I thought I did with a graph of 5 vertices. However, immediately after the question, there's another one which asks to prove that no asymmetric graph of less than or equal to 5 vertices exist. (Image to be attached). Could you show me why the graph I constructed is not asymmetric? [image: Image of the graph]I have highlighted the vertices by circling in green. Thank you!

Comment: "crystal math" is the best screen name I've seen here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me name the vertices. The top left is A, the top right is B, the middle is C, the bottom left is D and the bottom right is E.

Then you can use this permutation: $\{A,B,C,D,E\}\to\{E,B,D,C,A\}$

Comment: I posted an incorrect image. I'll fix it soon

Comment: Yes you're correct I forgot to draw an edge and the first image I posted is symmetric but I have edited it now to show the correct graph.

Comment: I changed the answer according to your new graph.

Answer (score 1):

In your first posting, the graph consisted of two disjoint triangles on vertices a,b,c and c,d,e, say, where c is the common vertex. A symmetry of the graph is the transposition (a,b) and another is to interchange d and e. One can also permute the two sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{d,e\}$.

In your second posting, the graph again had five vertices, where there was a unique vertex of degree 4. Any symmetry must therefore fix this vertex.  If this vertex is removed, then the remaining graph is the path graph $P_4$ on four vertices, which does have a nontrivial symmetry: one can interchange the first and last vertex of the path and interchange the second and third vertex of the path. Hence, the given graph has a nontrivial symmetry.

Comment: I posted the wrong image at first. I have updated it now

Comment: I've appended another paragraph for the new graph.